# Tikz - Drawing in the unit circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode

I am working on learning how to use tikz for mathematical drawings and I am currently trying to make... well... if you read or typeset the code you will get the idea.

If you look at the results the lines on either side of the y axis are not touching the top/bottom of the circle. However, I think they should (assuming I did my math right).

Any given point of the unit circle is `(sin(\x),cos(\x))` I know `cos(\x)` is `\x/8` thus `sin(\x)` is `1-\x/8*\x/8` (according to everyone fav trig identity).

Then when I draw a line, `(\x/8,0) -- +(0,1-\x/8*\x/8)` this should reach the top.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your time.

My Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
  \coordinate [label=left:$O$] (O) at (0,0);
  %Draw the Circle around it all
  \draw[semithick] (0,0) circle (1);
  %Draw lines to the top
  \foreach \x in {-4,...,4}
    \draw[red,very thick] (\x/8,0) -- +(0,1-\x/8*\x/8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

It is simply due to a forgotten square root step. It can be solved by adding `sqrt`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
  \node[left] (O) at (0,0) {$O$};
  %Draw the Circle around it all
  \draw[semithick] (0,0) circle (1);
  %Draw lines to the top
  \foreach \x in {-4,...,4}
    \draw[red,very thick] (\x/8,0) -- +(0,{sqrt(1-\x/8*\x/8)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```